# Blurred/smeared/overlapping ListActivity with CheckedTextView - acts like an image

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

I'm using ListView with CheckedTextView elemenets to show checklist.

And it works well on 2 phones i tried (Both KitKat), but i have problem on device called RuggedPad ([link](http://www.chinacruiser.com/product/buy-cheap-t70-outdoor-rugged-tablet-pc-wholesale/)), which also has Android 4.1.1

Problem is that instead of list, it is showing some kind of bitmap(?) - effect is that you if u scroll it overlaps itself(screenshots attached), and is not checkable.

[image: List start]
[image: After scrolling]

Tried to redraw listActivity on scroll :

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    getListView().invalidate();
    getListView().invalidateViews();
    getListView().requestLayout();
}
```

Also tried to disable drawing cache:

```
    getListView().setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Still does nothing.

Here is my code creating ListView:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    type = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_TYPE);
    String breakdown = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_DATA);

    try {
        JSONData = new ArrayList<Model>();
        JSONArray breakdownJSON = new JSONArray(breakdown);
        for (int i = 0; i < breakdownJSON.length(); i++) {
            JSONData.add(new Model(breakdownJSON.getJSONObject(i)));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        finish();
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Model>(this, R.layout.action_list, JSONData) {
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    };
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().requestFocusFromTouch();
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    for (int i = 0; i < JSONData.size(); i++) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(i, JSONData.get(i).checked);
    }
    getListView().setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
}
```

And .xml row definition:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/action_list_textview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
android:textSize="22sp"
/>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found reason after couple of hours.

Problem was in "android:theme" field for that activity:

```
android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
```

was causing all the problem.